# delete image attachments of a custom post type except featured image

Tags: attachments

I have a custom-post-type called "newcomer". I am trying to put together a function which would delete all image attachments (except featured image) of a custom-post-type when the CPT post is updated or published.  But this does not seem to be working, what am I doing wrong ?

```
function delete_extra_images() {
        if ( $post->post_type == 'newcomer' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
            $attachments = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
            ));

            if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, false ); 
            }
            }
        }   

    }
    add_action( 'publish_newcomer', 'delete_extra_images' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
add_action('save_post', function($post_id, $post, $update){

    if ( $post->post_type === 'newcomer' && $post->post_status === 'publish' ) {

        $attachments = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
        $featured_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        //unset the featured image by ID if it exists
        unset($attachments[$featured_id]);

        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, false ); 
        }

    }

}, 10, 3);
```

Note: You can forgoe wrapping the `foreach` statement in a conditional checking the state of the `$attachments` variable as `get_attached_media()` casts its result to an array internally. Of course if you wish to be prudent in the event core internals change then just cast it yourself or add back your conditional check.

Useful reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media

Comment: works nicely, i should have tried `save_post`. Is there a way my code would have worked with `publish_"custom_post_type"`, basically I would like to know where my code has gone wrong.

Comment: @gurung Using the `publish_{post_type}` hook will also work but be aware that this hook will only fire when a post of your desired type transitions to the status of **publish** from any **other** status, for example from **draft** to **publish**. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions for reference. Most likely in your scenario, `save_post` is the more suitable hook for your needs.

Comment: for what purpose are these arguments here `$post_id, $post, $update` ??

Comment: @gurung These arguments are passed to your callback function in `wp-includes/post.php` line 3541, you will note: `do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );`. Thus they are available for use within your callback, respectively `$post_ID` is the Post ID of the current object being saved, `$post` is the entire current `WP_Post` object and `$update` denotes (to quote core) *"Whether this is an existing post being updated or not."*